# slice func not working in text/template in go

Tags: go, go-templates

this is my template code snippet

```
                     {{ if eq .Method "GET" -}}
                            {{ if eq (slice .SummeryAsComment 7 10) "all"}}
                                getall(w,r)
                            {{ else }}
                                getbyid(w,r)
                            {{ end }}
                      {{- end}}
```

running this gives me the following error.

> error generating code: error parsing user-provided template
>   "chi-handler.tmpl": template: chi-handler.tmpl:123: function "slice"
>   not defined

But I checked it is one of the predefined function [available](https://golang.org/pkg/text/template/)

> slice
>
> slice returns the result of slicing its first argument by the
>     remaining arguments. Thus "slice x 1 2" is, in Go syntax, x[1:2],
>     while "slice x" is x[:], "slice x 1" is x[1:], and "slice x 1 2 3"
>     is x[1:2:3]. The first argument must be a string, slice, or array.

So why is this not working? 
I am actually editing a few templates provided by oapi-codegen [repo](https://github.com/deepmap/oapi-codegen). But this should work there too. Shouldn't it?

EDIT:
Changing version didn't work.

```
go version
go version go1.14.3 linux/amd64
```

I would like to explain what I am doing.

I am working with openAPI to generate a server-code boilerplate. So the templates are provided in that oapi codegen repo above. But I don't want the exact boilerplate code so I need to change the templates. The steps for changing code is provided [here](https://github.com/deepmap/oapi-codegen#making-changes-to-code-generation). More specifically I am doing the following.

> Alternatively, you can provide custom templates to override built-in
>   ones using the -templates flag specifying a path to a directory
>   containing templates files. These files must be named identically to
>   built-in template files (see pkg/codegen/templates/*.tmpl in the
>   source code), and will be interpreted on-the-fly at run time.

I am running these commands after i have my templates ready:

```
$ go get github.com/deepmap/oapi-codegen/cmd/oapi-codegen
$ oapi-codegen \
    -templates my-templates/ \
    -generate types,server \
    example-expanded.yaml
```

*my-templates* contains the templates I have changed. This [dir](https://github.com/deepmap/oapi-codegen/tree/master/pkg/codegen/templates) contains all the templates and I am changing a few of them and followed the steps as directed here.

Comment: Upgrade to Go 1.13 or later.

Comment: [Go 1.13 release notes](https://golang.org/doc/go1.13#text/template) to expand on what Cerise Limón said. Note that <https://golang.org/pkg> always renders the docs on the latest released Go version, and both the compiler, tooling and the standard library in the series of 1.x releases are free to add new stuff provided they do not break what's already there—according to the [compatibility promise](https://golang.org/doc/go1compat).

Comment: @CeriseLimón changing version did not work. Still getting the same error. I have added more details to the question.

Comment: For what it's worth, the feature works on Go 1.14.3 running in the playground https://play.golang.org/p/5J8gZAfA5U2.

Comment: What's the data type for `.SummeryAsComment `?